# Calling Save as Dialogue box in oracle forms 6i

Tags: excel, oracle

I have been using this standard code for generating an excel file in Oracle 6i forms. I need to know two things;

1. A code line to be added to this code so when i press button it shows 'generating excel file' until it finishes generating.
2. When its done generating file, instead of saving on D, it gives me a dialogue box of where to save my generated file.

   ```
   declare
   application ole2.obj_type;
   workbooks ole2.obj_type;
   workbook ole2.obj_type;
   worksheets ole2.obj_type;
   worksheet ole2.obj_type;
   cell ole2.obj_type;
   arglist ole2.list_type;
   row_num number;
   col_num number;
   fontObj ole2.obj_type;
   cursor rec is select emp_code,emp_name,to_char(date_of_birth,'dd/mm/rrrr') date_of_birth from employee_master where date_of_birth is not null;
   procedure SetCellValue(rowid number,colid number,cellValue varchar) is
   begin
     arglist := ole2.create_arglist;
     ole2.add_arg(arglist,rowid);
     ole2.add_arg(arglist,colid);
     cell:= ole2.get_obj_property(worksheet,'Cells',arglist);
     fontObj := ole2.get_obj_property(cell,'Font');
     ole2.destroy_arglist(arglist);
     ole2.set_property(cell,'value',cellValue);
     ole2.set_property(fontObj,'Size',16);
     ole2.set_property(fontObj,'BOLD',1);
     ole2.set_property(fontObj,'ColorIndex',7);
     ole2.release_obj(cell);
   end SetCellValue;
   procedure app_init is
    begin
       application := ole2.create_obj('Excel.Application');
       ole2.set_property(application,'Visible',true);
       workbooks := ole2.get_obj_property(application,'workbooks');
       workbook := ole2.invoke_obj(workbooks,'add');
       worksheets := ole2.get_obj_property(application,'worksheets');
       worksheet := ole2.invoke_obj(worksheets,'add');
       ole2.set_property(worksheet,'Name','Emp Sheet');
    end app_init;

   procedure save_excel(path varchar,filename varchar) is
   begin
     OLE2.Release_Obj(worksheet);
     OLE2.Release_Obj(worksheets);
     -- Save the Excel file created
     If path is not null then
        Arglist := OLE2.Create_Arglist;
        OLE2.Add_Arg(Arglist,path||'\'||file_name||'.xls');
        OLE2.Invoke(workbook, 'SaveAs', Arglist);
        OLE2.Destroy_Arglist(Arglist);
     end if;
   end save_excel;

   begin
    app_init;
     row_num:=1;
     col_num:=1;
     SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,'Emp Code');
     col_num:=col_num + 1;
     SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,'Emp Name');
     col_num:=col_num + 1;
     SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,'Date of Birth');
     for i in rec loop
         row_num:=row_num + 1;
         col_num:=1;
         SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,i.emp_code);     
         col_num:=2;
         SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,i.emp_name);     
         col_num:=3;
         SetCellValue(row_num,col_num,i.date_of_birth);        
     end loop;       
       save_excel('d:\excel_export','emp_data');             
     OLE2.Release_Obj(workbook);
     OLE2.Release_Obj(workbooks);
     OLE2.Release_Obj(application);    
    end;
   ```

Comment: for message 'generating excel file' try to wrap in a block and show the message with alert or message.

Comment: @MuhammadNadeem Can you please show me how would i do that with code? am new to oracle